# Specifying org-babel or org-export output path

Tags: org-export, org-publish

I'd like my exports to go into a specific directory. Right now everything is output in the same path as the source file.

There's a [very old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559753/emacs-org-mode-export-to-another-directory) with sample code that seems get me part way there:

```
 (defun org-export-output-file-name-modified (orig-fun extension &optional subtreep pub-dir)
    (unless pub-dir
      (setq pub-dir "exported-org-files")
      (unless (file-directory-p pub-dir)
        (make-directory pub-dir)))
    (apply orig-fun extension subtreep pub-dir nil))

 (advice-add 'org-export-output-file-name :around #'org-export-output-file-name-modified)
```

However HTML exports don't include images, either static ones or inserted via PlantUML.
Latex/PDF export works fine though.

Is there a better option?

**Edit**:

I tried the following org-export code:

```
    (require 'ox-publish)
    (setq org-publish-project-alist
          '(("org-notes"
             :base-directory "~/Dropbox/orgmode/"
             :publishing-directory "~/export"
             :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
            )

            ("org-static"
             :base-extension "png"
             :base-directory "~/Dropbox/orgmode/"
             :publishing-directory "~/export"
             :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
             )

            ("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))

            )
          )
```

The images are not being moved to `~/export` though.

**Edit 2**:

Apologies for the paths; I fixed them now. So the issue seems to be Babel and plantuml. I have the following org-file:

```
#+title: org-export-test

* Meta                                                            :noexport:

Meta section. We don't expect to see it exported due to the ~noexport~ tag.

* Intro

This is an intro section.



* Plantuml section

What we store.

#+begin_src plantuml :file plantuml_dirgram.png

  @startuml
  hide circle
  skinparam linetype ortho

  entity "Table" as EventLog {
          id : number <<generated>>
          --
  }
  @enduml
#+end_src
```

The *PlantUML* section contains a directive to output to `plantuml_diagram.png` in the same path as the org file.

However when I run `org-publish-current-file`, the HTML file is generated, but the `png` is not. If I generate the png file manually into `~/Dropbox/orgmode`, it's still not copied into `~/export`.

Comment: That's because you can't just move the HTML file: all the images (etc) that are linked from the HTML file have to be moved as a unit, *OR* the export has to be modified to produce different URLs for the links. However, the method that is built-in to Org mode is [Publishing](https://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing.html#Publishing): `publishing` is essentially `exporting + moving files to a publishing directory` - you have to write a (for simple cases, small) config file (there is an example in the manual) but it works very well.

Comment: @NickD I updated the question with `org-publish` functionality, but still no luck. I don't see any errors or anything useful in *Messages*. `toggle-debug-on-error` is set as well.

Comment: `~/export`? You mean `~/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~appsonthemove~beorg/Documents/org-roam/export`?

Comment: Start with a small example with images and the "complex" config file example (which is pretty simple really). Make sure you use relative path names in the Org mode links. I presume you got the config file from the [publishing tutorial on Worg](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html). Where are your images kept in relation to your Org mode files? See the discussion about directory hierarchies in the tutorial. At least at first, make sure that you stay *very* close to the tutorial and  double-check all the settings.

Comment: @NickD, I update the question. Do you mind taking a look?

Comment: I will but it's not going to be immediate. Maybe at the end of the week...

Comment: @NickD thanks for all your help; I figured it out. See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was using `M-x org-publish-current-file` which does not respect project settings. As soon as I switched to `M-x org-publish-current-project` or `C-e P x` the export worked as expected.

Comment: There is something more to this I think: `org-publish-current-file` uses `org-publish-file`, the same function that is called from `org-publish-current-project`, so it most certainly respects project settings. I suspect there is something going on with the cache, but I'm not sure (and I don't have time to check now).